# Can php launch scripts without user interaction in order to interact with the database?

Tags: php, database, interaction

I've search on the web and apparently there is no way to launch a php script without user interaction.

Few advisors recommend me Cron but I am not sure this is the right way to go.

I am building a website where auctions are possible just like ebay. And after an amount of time the objects are not available anymore and the auction is considered as finished.

I would like to know a way to interact with the database automatically.

Answer (score 2):

When do you need to know if an object is available? -> Only if someone asks.

And then you have the user interaction you are searching for.

It's something different if you want to, let's say, send an email to the winner of an auction. In this case you'd need some timer set to the ending time of the auction. The easiest way to do this would be a cron job...

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Cron is a valid one of them and the one I would recommend if its available.

Another is to check before handling each request related to an object whether it is still valid. If it is not, you can delete it from the database on-the-fly (or do whatever you need to) and display a different page.

Also you could store the time at which your time-based script was run last in the database and compare that time with the current time. If the delay is large enough, you can run your time based code. However, this is prone to race conditions if multiple users hit the page at the same time, so the script may run multiple times (maybe this can be avoided using locks or anything though).

Answer (score 1):

To edit cronjobs from the shell: `crontab -e`

A job to run every 10 minutes: `*/10 * * * * curl "http://example.com/finished.php"`

[TheGeekStuff.com cron Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Use heartbeat/bot implement
ation

Answer (score 0):

Cron job that runs pretty frequently or a program that starts on boot and runs continuously (maybe sleeping periodically) is the way to go.  With a cron job you'll need to make sure that you don't have two running at any given time or write it such that it doesn't matter if you have more than one working at any given time.  With "resident" program you'll need to figure out how to handle the case when it crashes unexpectedly.

I wouldn't rely on this mechanism to actually close the auction, though.  That should be handled in your database/web site.  That is, the auction has a close time and either the database constraints or your code makes it impossible to bid on a closed auction.  Notifying the winner and seller, setting up the payment process, etc. are things your service/scheduled task could do.